# Will you get the benefits of IQueryable if you use entity projections?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Lets say I have a method like this:

```
IQueryable<MyFlatObject> GetMyFlatObjects()
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        return context.MyEntities.Select(x => new MyFlatObject()
                                                  {
                                                     Property1 = x.PropertyA,
                                                     Property2 = x.PropertyB,
                                                     Property3 = x.PropertyC,
                                                  });
    }
}
```

Now if I call:

```
MyService.GetMyFlatObjects().Where(x => x.Property1 == "test");
```

Sanity check. This filter will not propagate to my database store (like if I had just queried my entities), but instead I will get all results back and be using LINQ-to-objects to filter. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, it's not right. First, it doesn't query anything because you are only extending an `IQueryable<T>` to a new `IQueryable<T>`. If you call `ToList()` or anything else that causes the query to execute you'll get an exception because the context has already been disposed at the end of the `using` block. If you don't dispose the context the `Where` filter will be translated to SQL and executed in the database. I believe it will behave the same way as if you would apply the `Where` to `PropertyA` *before* the `Select`.

Comment: Right, I didn't think about the context being disposed when I posted. Behind the scenes I am really using a repository abstraction. If this really does pass on the filter and correctly map it to the original entity property that would be really nice. I was surprised I couldn't find much about this.

Comment: @AdamD: You should test it, I am not 100% sure. But If I remember correctly I have asked myself some time ago what happens with such a query and I tested it and came to the conclusion above. `Select` returns an `IQueryable` after all that still holds a SQL provider reference and a connection, so it's still LINQ to Entities and not LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Ok just checked sql profiler to test it out. It works just like you thought and correctly mapped the entity property into the sql query. I also checked a calculated property (i.e. MyFlatObject.Property2 = MyEntity.PropertyA + MyEntity.PropertyB) and it even mapped that correctly to sql. Pretty impressive.